# Spiral Graph in R

Tags: r, time, graph, spiral

How to create a spiral graph in R? Is there any package for this kind of analysis? Or is there any other way to visualize time oriented data (regarding periodicity)?

Comment: generate a set of data points that represent a spiral...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824391/how-to-draw-a-spiral-in-canvas

Comment: @Radim: If you show us some sample data and give a clearer description of what you want, we can provide more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For examining periodicity, [cycle plots](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/guests/intro_to_cycle_plots.pdf) (pdf) work well.  There are also many, many functions for analysing periodicity in time series.  Start with `stl` and `periodicity` in the `xts` package.

Using `ggplot2`, you can create a spiral graph like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(beavers)
p <- ggplot(beaver1, aes(time, temp, colour = day)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  coord_polar(theta = "x")
p
```