# How to create Phyllotaxis Spirals with R

Tags: r, plot

How can I create Phyllotaxis spirals in R? Example of such images is shown at the bottom of this page: http://www.mathrecreation.com/2008/09/phyllotaxis-spirals.html  The image is attached below:

[image]

These are also similar to Fermat's spiral: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_spiral

I searched and found this method: [Spiral Graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828350/spiral-graph-in-r)
but it does not create one of above patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula from http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop-ch4.pdf

```
golden.ratio = (sqrt(5) + 1)/2
fibonacci.angle=360/(golden.ratio^2)
c=1
num_points=630
x=rep(0,num_points)
y=rep(0,num_points)

for (n in 1:num_points) {
    r=c*sqrt(n)
    theta=fibonacci.angle*(n)
    x[n]=r*cos(theta)
    y[n]=r*sin(theta)
}
plot(x,y,axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE,pch=19,cex=1)
```