# How to plot a curved bar plot in Python or R

Tags: python, r

I need to plot a bar plot. Because there are too many tick labels along the x axis (as shown in Figure 1), I want to plot a circular-like, curved bar plot (as shown in Figure 2). Does any one know how to do this in Python or R? BTW, you are also appreciated if you can provide another equivalent replacement for Figure 1.

[image]

R toy example, conventional bar plot

```
yyy = runif(500)
names(yyy) = paste0('label', 1:500)
barplot(yyy)
```

Python toy example, conventional bar plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xxx = ['lable' + str(x) for x in list(range(1, 501))]
yyy = np.random.uniform(size=500)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(list(range(1, 501)), yyy)
ax.set_xticks(list(range(1, 501)))
ax.set_xticklabels(xxx)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think this will be particularly easy in either R or Python, but it should be possible. I did find a [cool example of this](https://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/027e163073864ef2ac4ceb5c2c0bf616) done in Javascript/D3.

Comment: Thanks Marius, that's fantastic. I can plot using js instead. ^_^

Comment: I find a post on stackoverlow for creating condegram spiral plot using R, [How to Create A Time-Spiral Graph Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480841/how-to-create-a-time-spiral-graph-using-r)

Answer (score -1):

As @Nan Zhou commented, here is an approach, you can generate the spiral [making the points for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6828471/7654451):

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = car, y = disp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   coord_polar()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Tito Sanz , the polar graph is good but I don't think it's a good solution for my problem. The problem caused by too many x axis tick labels remains in polar graph. According to yours, another solution is multiple layer circular plot, with each layer showing a part of all labels. The problem of circular plot is different layers are discrete. I prefer to spiral plot which shows all labels in a continuous way.

Comment: Ohh I see. Sorry I misunderstood the problem.