# trigonometry using javascript

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I am trying to draw the cos curve using javascript. I expected to see a nice cos curve going accross the webpage. like this...
[image]

I added 200 to move the curve down so I could see the whole thing. I multiply by 100 because there are no decimal places in html. If you look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RN7WN/8/) it is a mess

http://jsfiddle.net/RN7WN/8/

```
$(function(){    
    for (i=0; i<500; i++){ 
        var el = $('<div class="dot"></div>'); 
        var y = Math.cos(i*100) * 100 + 200;
        var x = i ;
        el.css({ 'left' : x+'px' , 'top':y+ 'px'});
        $('#main').after(el);  
    } 
});​
```

Comment: Cos param is in radians!

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos the `cos` function requires a parameter in radians. You might want to try converting from degrees to radians to see if it helps...

Comment: You would probably have better luck drawing curved lines using something like canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824391/how-to-draw-a-spiral-in-canvas'

Comment: You might be interest in this simple hack I made a while back. It graphs equations to a canvas element: http://joncraton.org/eqgraph/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigonometric functions use [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), not degrees. To convert between degrees and radians, use the formula

```
radians = Math.PI / 180 * degrees
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/RN7WN/12/) an updated version of the fiddle that shows something recognizable.

Comment: thanks,  here it is with changing the x and y (in html y counts down) http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/pXeAb/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/RN7WN/13/

```
$(function(){    
    for (i=0; i< 2 * Math.PI; i+=0.01){
        //alert('aa');   
        var el = $('<div class="dot"></div>'); 
        var x = Math.cos(i) * 100 + 100;
        var y = i * 100 + 50;
        el.css({ 'left' : x+'px' , 'top':y+ 'px'});
        $('#main').after(el); 
        //$('#main').after('<p>'+ l +'</p>');
    } 
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

As I explained before in my comment, you need to convert from degrees to radians by multiplying by `Math.PI / 180`.

For example:

```
$(function(){    
  for (i=0; i<400; i++){
    var el = $('<div class="dot"></div>'); 
    var x = Math.sin(i * (Math.PI/180)) * 100;
    var y = i + 200;
    el.css({ 'left' : x+'px' , 'top':y+ 'px'});
    $('#main').after(el); 
  } 
});​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YqkKe/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating the change.