# draw spiral circles in canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I wants to draw this pattern spiral in `canvas` i am using below code
need your help for further draw circles.

```
 // get the canvas element using the DOM
 var canvas = document.getElementById('circlecanvas');
 // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
 if (canvas.getContext){
    // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Draw shapes
    ctx.beginPath();
    //context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
    for (i=0;i<9;i++){
        ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, i, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are experiencing? Nothing happens? Got an error? etc?

Comment: only one circle is drawing.. but wants as seems in pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is a spiral...
I am posting the pseudo code to draw an archimedian spiral below :-
NB- angle is a variable.. that you adjust accordingly...

```
for (i=0; i< 720; i++) {
  angle = 0.1 * i;
  x=(1+angle)*Math.cos(angle);
  y=(1+angle)*Math.sin(angle);
  drawlineTo(x, y);
}
```

Comment: all that i could find was this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824391/drawing-a-spiral-on-an-html-canvas-using-javascript

Comment: @PuzzledBoy..lemme knw whether it helped.. :)